# Add a geom_vline to autoplot forecast

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting

I am trying to add a vertical line to a forecast. Say I have the following

```
library(fpp2)
data(insurance)
autoplot(insurance)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept = "2004-07")) #problem line
```

How do I get `geom_vlinee()` to place nice with `autoplot()`?

Comment: @RichardTelford what would that look like for just a single xintercept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your `xintercept` in the same type as the x-axis of the plot. In this case, insurance is a timeseries so you can find out how the dates are stored with

```
time(insurance)
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul
2002 2002.000 2002.083 2002.167 2002.250 2002.333 2002.417 2002.500
2003 2003.000 2003.083 2003.167 2003.250 2003.333 2003.417 2003.500
2004 2004.000 2004.083 2004.167 2004.250 2004.333 2004.417 2004.500
2005 2005.000 2005.083 2005.167 2005.250
```

So we need a year plus a fraction for the month

```
autoplot(insurance)+
   geom_vline(xintercept = 2004 + (07 - 1) / 12)
```